# SSRS Excel Export

Tags: excel, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reportingservices-2005

We migrated our old SSRS 2005 reports to 2008. Now, when we try to export the reports to Excel, we noticed that the Sheet naming convention has changed.

In 2005, it will be like this:

> Document Map | Sheet **1** | Sheet 2 | Sheet 3...

Now, it is showing:

> Document Map | Sheet **2** | Sheet 3 | Sheet 4...

Is this a default feature? Is there a way to revert this to the old scheme? I have tried changing the tab names, but probably the noob-ness of my SSRS skills is preventing me to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SSRS 2008R2 you can control the tab names by using the [Page name property](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/robertbruckner/archive/2010/04/25/report-design-reset-page-number-on-group.aspx). You should be able to use these to recreate the old naming convention. But this will only work in 2008r2.

SSRS 2012 will be changing the export to Excel functionality again as it will now use .xlsx. So you should avoid relying on a solution that depends on the tab names of Excel. If this is for some data interchange, then maybe look at SSIS instead?

Comment: Thanks, our users just need to send the report without the Document Map sheet. The 'Sheet 2' initial value confuses them. Will try this out and let you know.